# Save output of a python function as Data Frame

Tags: python, dataframe, output

I have the following got that gets a list of coins from a website. the output of this code gets printed in Jupypter. How can I assign the output to a variable/to a dataframe so that I can use it later as in input for another function?

```
import time
import requests 

url = 'https://web-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest'

 
for start in range(1, 20000, 5000):

    params = {
        'start': start,
        'limit': 5000,
    }

    r = requests.get(url, params=params)
    data = r.json()
    
    for number, item in enumerate(data['data']):
        print(f"{start+number:4} | {item['symbol']:5} | {item['date_added'][:10]}")
```

The output looks like this:

```
 1 | BTC   | 2013-04-28
 2 | ETH   | 2015-08-07
 3 | USDT  | 2015-02-25
```

I tried the Str() function in Python but it prints only the last coin in the list.

Comment: checkout [pandas.read_json](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html) documentation for a function to convert json directly to a dataframe, then simply return the dataframe

Answer (score 1):

You can create a list:

```
out = []
```

and then within the loop, append to it:

```
 out.append({
        'num': f'{start + number:4}',
        'symbol': f'{item["symbol"]:5}',
        'date': item['date_added'][:10]},
    )
```

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests

url = 'https://web-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest'

out = []
for start in range(1, 20000, 5000):

    params = {
        'start': start,
        'limit': 5000,
    }

    r = requests.get(url, params=params)
    data = r.json()

    for number, item in enumerate(data['data']):
        out.append({
            'num': f'{start + number:4}',
            'symbol': f'{item["symbol"]:5}',
            'date': item['date_added'][:10]},
        )

df = pd.DataFrame(out)
print(df.to_string(index=False))
```

Output:

```
num                  symbol       date
   1                   BTC   2013-04-28
   2                   ETH   2015-08-07
   3                   USDT  2015-02-25
   4                   USDC  2018-10-08
   5                   BNB   2017-07-25
   6                   XRP   2013-08-04
   7                   BUSD  2019-09-20
   8                   DOGE  2013-12-15
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put your results in a list like so:

```py
import time
import requests 

url = 'https://web-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest'
results = []
 
for start in range(1, 20000, 5000):

    params = {
        'start': start,
        'limit': 5000,
    }

    r = requests.get(url, params=params)
    data = r.json()
    
    for number, item in enumerate(data['data']):
        results.append({
            "coin": item['symbol'],
            "date": item['date_added']
        })
```

You can then use the results list directly, or you can convert it to a dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd
results_df = pd.DataFrame(results)
```

Comment: Great, but how is this any different then the above _already answered_ answer?

Comment: it's the same i was just a bit late X) and i didn't see your answer @MendelG